# Laravel 8 route not found using jetstream nav menu

Tags: php, laravel

Fairly new to laravel 8 with some experience with laravel 7. I'm trying to add some additional pages to the default dashboard nav menu. however after adding the code, as I expect it to be, I get this error:

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [accounts.index] not defined. (View: /home/some/path/resources/views/navigation-menu.blade.php)
```

So here is what I have done code wise:
in web.php i have the following route:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])
    ->get('/accounts', [AccountController::class, 'index'])
   ->name('accounts');
```

I have a controller /app/Http/Controllers/AccountController.php as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Account;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AccountController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index() {
        $accounts = Account::all();

        return View::make('pages.accounts.index')->with('accounts', $accounts);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return View::make('pages.accounts.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I have a Model /app/Models/Account.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Eloquent;

class Account extends Eloquent
{

}
```

I also have blade templates for this page which i wont list for brevity as don't think this matters with the issue and at this point if I navigate to {url}/accounts the accounts index page is shown as intended.

However now I want to move this functionality into the jetstream dashboard so I can cut down on some development time and theme it similar to the default laravel concept.

The first thing I need is to add a new nav item next to Dashboard so I amended the default navigation-menu.blade.php file (/resources/views/navigation-menu.blade.php) by copying what it uses for dashboard and updating:

```
...
                <!-- Navigation Links -->
                <div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
                    <x-jet-nav-link href="{{ route('dashboard') }}" :active="request()->routeIs('dashboard')">
                        {{ __('Dashboard') }}
                    </x-jet-nav-link>
                </div>
                <div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
                    <x-jet-nav-link href="{{ route('accounts.index') }}" :active="request()->routeIs('accounts.index')">
                        {{ __('Accounts') }}
                    </x-jet-nav-link>
                </div>
            </div>
...
```

It is at this point when reloading the page throws the error. Anyone know what is causing this? I initially tried without using .index as this is the default anyway right?

I have also tried to follow a few tuts on doing this ((https://eheidi.dev/blog/creating-a-multi-user-to-do-application-with-laravel-jetstream-2p1k)) but I get the same error when i reload my page after editing the navigation-manu.blade.php file so I'm at a loss. I'm developing this on ubuntu 20.04

thanks

Craig

*** EDIT ***
I have updated my route to be a resource for better use moving forward.

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])
    ->resource('/accounts', [AccountController::class, 'index'])
    ->name('accounts.index');
```

Tested this without the amend in navigation-menu.blade.php and all still worked added back the amends and same error.

*** EDIT 2 ***
I have I think narrowed this down to what should be in the navigation-menu file and the web routes file. I have further amended my web.php code as per point 2 of an answer below by Chadrack:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])
    ->resource('/accounts', AccountController::class)
    ->only( ['index', 'create', 'store', 'update'])
    ->name('index', 'accounts');
```

The snippet I added to the navigation-menu.blade.php is:

```
                <div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
                    <x-jet-nav-link href="{{ route('accounts') }}" :active="request()->routeIs('accounts')">
                        {{ __('Accounts') }}
                    </x-jet-nav-link>
                </div>
```

This is still throwing the error, also if i add .index to route function ( route('accounts.index') ) I still get an error (either Route [accounts.index] not defined or Route [accounts] not defined

*** EDIT 3 ***
I repeated the initial tutorial I had tried and failed with (https://eheidi.dev/blog/creating-a-multi-user-to-do-application-with-laravel-jetstream-2p1k) but as with my issue here after i have added the x-jet nav-link section to the blade template and added the route, when i reload i get the same error (with the new defined route) Route [dashboard-todo] not defined. So if the issue I get is the same for both options then I must be missing something here? As pointed out before I have tried every combination of route type. It works using the url [url]/accounts until I add the link into the nav-bar. The Dashboard does work when no changes are made to the navigation-menu.blade.php

Answer (score 1):

you need to call your route using it's name.

in your definition you are define the route with the name `accounts` while you are calling a route named by `accounts.index`

replace your route

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])
    ->get('/accounts', [AccountController::class, 'index'])
    ->name('accounts');
```

By

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])
    ->get('/accounts', [AccountController::class, 'index'])
    ->name('accounts.index');
           // note this
```

Comment: I had tried this already as well as using just accounts for all places but same kind of error (just says accouns instead of accounts.index in the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your route name is accounts and you called accounts.index, it will not work, you have two possibilities to fix them.

1. replace :

   `Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/accounts', [AccountController::class, 'index'])->name('accounts')`

by :

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])
        ->get('/accounts', [AccountController::class, 'index'])
        ->name('accounts.index')
```

2. You can also use resources as method :

   ```
    Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->resource('/accounts', AccountController::class)->only(['index', 'create','store',update]);
   ```

Comment: I tried these suggestions but still no joy. Please see my new Edits at the bottom of the question (EDIT 2 and EDIT 3). I use the exact same string in the Route name (in web.php) and in the nav-bar for both the route() and routeIs() functions (in navigation-menu.blade.php). Surely it should just work right?

Answer (score 0):

So just in case anyone else had this issue, I managed to fix it as follows:

First i used the following in web.php:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->resource('/accounts', \App\Http\Controllers\AccountController::class);
```

Note no name element and the full path to the controller (in addition to it being in a use at the top of web.api.

I then ran the following to clear my routes:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

I was then able to use the following in navigation-menu.blade.php:

```
    <x-jet-nav-link href="{{ route('accounts.index') }}" :active="request()->routeIs('accounts.index')">
        {{ __('Accounts') }}
    </x-jet-nav-link>
```

Note I call accounts.index here. Now when i go onto my dashboard I see the new menu item and can visit the page as required. I am now also able to add the other pages from this resource (ie create, edit, destroy).

Of note I'm not sure if i need the full path in the route, found this on another post on SO and now it is working as I expected I don't wish to upset the apple-cart.

thanks

Craig