# Can't get the new page to load following https://eheidi.dev/blog/creating-a-multi-user-to-do-application-with-laravel-jetstream-2p1k

Tags: php, laravel

I'm following the following tutorial to create a Todo object in laravel 8

https://eheidi.dev/blog/creating-a-multi-user-to-do-application-with-laravel-jetstream-2p1k

I follow the tutorial to the letter and all is fine until Step 3 when i edit the navigation-dropdown.blade.php at which point when i reload the page i get the following error:
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [accounts] not defined. (View: /home/{me}/{my-path}/resources/views/navigation-menu.blade.php)

My laravel is version 8 and the tutorial isn't clear on which version of laravel to use (just uses the latest). Is there some additional steps I need to get this to work with Laravel 8? Any other good tutorials on how to use Jetstream and add to the nav menu?

My installation exactly followed this tutorial so is a new build with no other components. Does Laravel have some php requirements I've missed?

Heres a brief overview of the process:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel mytodo
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -yq nodejs build-essential
composer require laravel/jetstream
php artisan jetstream:install livewire
npm install && npm run dev
php artisan migrate
```

I then load the browser and see the default view. I goto the /register view and create a user.

All great until this point and then it is step 3 of the tutorial:

```
cp resources/views/dashboard.blade.php resources/views/todo.blade.php
php artisan make:livewire todo.show
php artisan make:livewire todo.form
```

I then edit these templates:

```
#resources/views/todo.blade.php
<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            {{ __('My To-Do List') }}
        </h2>
    </x-slot>

    <div>
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-10 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            @livewire('todo.form')
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg">
                @livewire('todo.show')
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
```

and update the nav file

```
#resources/views/navigation-dropdown.blade.php
...
<!-- Navigation Links -->
                <div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
                    <x-jet-nav-link href="{{ route('dashboard') }}" :active="request()->routeIs('dashboard')">
                        {{ __('Dashboard') }}
                    </x-jet-nav-link>

                    <x-jet-nav-link href="{{ route('dashboard-todo') }}" :active="request()->routeIs('dashboard-todo')">
                        {{ __('To-Do List') }}
                    </x-jet-nav-link>
                </div>
...
```

I update the web.php file:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard/todo', function () {
    return view('todo');
})->name('dashboard-todo');
```

I then reload the page and expect to see a new menu item called to-do-list but at this point I get the error above.

When i remove the section from the nav menu it shows as it should (but obviously without the link to to-do-list).

This is as far as i got with this.

thanks

*** EDIT ***
Tutorial is 11 months old so probably Laravel 7? So what would of changed if anything?

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Question updated with content from the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I abandoned this in the end but I did get it working on another project.

[Laravel 8 route not found using jetstream nav menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69465183/laravel-8-route-not-found-using-jetstream-nav-menu/69709876#69709876)

It maybe that `php artisan route:clear` would resolve this one.